# Select top(1) occurence of a certain value in field sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose a table with 2 columns. One is char(1) and contains alphabet letters which can repeat themselves (not unique). The other column is an int column. What is the correct sql script to select each letter only once and specifically the row where the int column is max (the max int within the group of each letter) so for example If I have 3 rows with letter 'A' with corresponding integers 1,2,3 then only the (A , 3) row would be selected. Of course my real case is different than this but I simplified the example for clarity.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(intcol),charcol 
FROM tab
GROUP BY charcol
```

should do it

To handle the scenario mentioned in the comment

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT MAX(intcol) AS maxintcol,charcol 
    FROM tab
    GROUP BY charcol
)
SELECT t.*
FROM tab t JOIN cte c on c.maxintcol=t.intcol  AND c.charcol = t.charcol
```

Comment: Of course this is obvious ... thanks for answer I think I oversimplified the example ... the ideea was how I identify that specific row like in: supose you have a third column with a guid (in addition to the two columns mentioned in question) ... how do I find the guid corresponding to the (A,3) row in the question --- the guid corresponding to the unique occurence of each letter where the [int] is max for that letter

Comment: That does it ... Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(ID) As [MaxId], Letter
FROM Alphabets
GROUP BY Letter
```

Comment: Of course this is obvious ... thanks for answer I think I oversimplified the example ... the ideea was how I identify that specific row like in: supose you have a third column with a guid (in addition to the two columns mentioned in question) ... how do I find the guid corresponding to the (A,3) row in the question --- the guid corresponding to the unique occurence of each letter where the [int] is max for that letter